# Coordinate system doesn't contain values in the range -180 to 180 and -90 to 90

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, file-formats

I'm creating an android version of a PC program (I've contacted the company who owns the PC program, so it's legal). The program is in the core a GPS, but is used to navigate pre-defined routes for heavyweight transports, because they are not allowed to pass some bridges. However, that isn't very important for my problem. The program reads the coordinates from text files, so my app needs to do that too, but those coordinates are not in the range -180 to 180 and -90 to 90. So I can't really understand them. For example, one coordinate has these values:

**X**: *6603939,57000491*
**Y**: *575841,753705909*

I need to convert these coordinates to WGS84 coordinates (lon and lat) in order to be able to use them for what I want.

Comment: You need to provide more information on the source of these files, and a guess as to the possible units.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you to have a look at the webpage epsg.io. There you can search also for regions to see which EPSG-codes are common for these regions. As you have written in your profile that you are from Sweden, I guess the coordinates are from Sweden,too.
The best match i found so far was EPSG 3006 but i guess you flipped the x and y -values, is that possible?

if you flip x/y-Values and use EPSG3006 you end up in sweden in the middle of a road:
[image]
http://epsg.io/3006/map

Comment: Thanks! The location is correct :) So what coordinate system is it?

Comment: http://sv.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWEREF_99_TM

Comment: Ah, Thanks! This seems to be what i'm looking for.

Comment: Your welcome ;-)

Comment: One more thing. Do you know how I can convert them to polar coordinates?

Comment: I would suggest qgis or ogr2ogr depending on how often you need to convert coordinates. http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html  http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html

Comment: Sorry, wrong. I want to convert SWEREF99 coordinates to POLAR COORDINATES. Also, I need to convert them about once every second. Any suggestions?

Comment: [PROJ.4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) is an open source command line tool you can use. For your conversion it would look like `cs2cs +init=epsg:3006 +no_defs +to +init=epsg:4326 +no_defs` and then your swedish coordinates

Comment: Is there a java library for this which I can use in my android app?

Comment: Yes then better something like github.com/irstv/CTS or http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4j/ (for java) (proj4.js could still be interesting for someone who builds a native app with phonegap ;)

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12 - The term "polar coordinates" is ambiguous, so shouting doesn't help. Please **[edit]** the new info and question parts into the question.

Comment: @martinf [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system)

Comment: That is a mathematics reference, this is *geo*matics. You first talked of "normal" (longitude and latitude) coords. Polar coordinates can refer to relative planar coords or to a variation of lat-long coords -- you need to specify. And please put it all in the question.

Comment: @Thomas: I'd upvote your answer for the fine detective work you've done, except you've maintained the OP's near Angstrom-level of precision!

Comment: @martinf Is this bad in some way? To maintain the "precision"? The point is to answer the asked question, right?

Comment: Answer the Q and help out by correcting any (perhaps minor) faux pas. Excessive precision is a pet peeve of mine.

Comment: @martinf He did answer my question, and that's what the site is for. I don't understand the point of what you are saying. Where do you want to get? Also, what do you mean by shouting? You said `The term "polar coordinates" is ambiguous, so shouting doesn't help`

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12: Putting things in all caps (block capitals) is often considered to be shouting, not helpful. "Polar coords" could mean either (1) relative, planar, 2D, bearing and distance values, or (2) absolute, global, 3D, lat, long, and R values.

Comment: @martinf I did that instead of making it bold, I tried to show that it was important, if you understand what I mean.

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12 -- If you have a question about "polar coordinates" ask it in a separate question (and be careful to clearly define what you think polar coords are).