# Converting SWEREF99TM coordinates to the "standard" coordinate system (longitude and latitude)

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

I recently asked [a question about a coordinate system in a file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131638/coordinate-system-doesnt-contain-values-in-the-range-180-to-180-and-90-to-90), and found out that it used SWEREF99TM, but I can't figure out how to convert those coordinates to the ["geographic coordinate system"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system). I've found a bit about it on [lantmateriet.se](http://www.lantmateriet.se/en/Maps-and-geographic-information/GPS-and-geodetic-surveys/Reference-systems/Two-dimensional-systems/SWEREF-99-projections/). It says that:

> It is an advantage for many different applications at the national
>   level if the whole Sweden can be mapped seamlessly, i.e. on one
>   projection with position given in one co-ordinate system. A rigid
>   application of, for example, UTM in Sweden would require a division
>   into three zones.
>
> The definition of a dedicated projection based on a meridian 15° E of
>   Greenwich, with a scale factor of 0.9996, with the Equator as the
>   origin for N co-ordinates and with E co-ordinates measured from the
>   central meridian and increasing eastwards (the central meridian is
>   assigned a value of 500 000 m to avoid negative values) will give
>   consistency with UTM in the major part of the country.

I still can't really figure out how to convert it, but I would be glad if someone could help me with it. I got a suggestion to use the java library *proj4j* (because I'm going to convert it using java, and then use the coordinates in an android app).
But I can't figure out how to use that either, and I also want to do it myself. I don't really like libraries. I want to do stuff myself. Don't know why. It just is like that :)

What does the *scale factor* mean, and what unit is the coordinates measured with, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admire your gusto for thinking about converting your XYs to lat/longs yourself, but most libraries exist for a reason. :-)

If you are undeterred, then I strongly encourage you to download the excellent [OGP Guidance Note 7-2](http://www.iogp.org/pubs/373-07-2.pdf) "Coordinate Conversions and Transformations" as it contains the definitions to mapping terms, and Transverse Mercator (the projection of SWEREF99 TM) starts on page 45. The formula for converting to lat/longs begins on page 49 and carries on for several pages.

Comment: Thanks! I'll defenitely read the book! I couldn't find any which looked good, but I'll try this one.

Comment: So SWEREF99 TM uses Transverse Mercator? It those two equivalent? My bad. I found it on wikipedia :) (They are the same)

Comment: After a bit of reading and trying, I think I'll use the Java library *JMapProjLib* anyway (instead of doing it on my own). :)